# How do I connect to MongoDB using Python and convert the cursor object output into a form that I can understand?

Tags: python, mongodb

Please see my below code

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

# Provide the connection details

hostname = 'website.com' #server hostname
port = xxxx #  server port
username = 'xxx'  # If authentication is required
password = 'xxx'  # If authentication is required

# Create a MongoClient instance
client = MongoClient(hostname, port, username=username, password=password)
print("Connection to MongoDB established")
db = client['databaseName']   #  db name

# Access a collection (similar to a table in relational databases)
collection = db['collectionName']
myquery = {"QueryName"}

mydoc = collection.find(myquery)

print(mydoc)

client.close()
```

When I run the code I receive the following output.
**Connection to MongoDB established
<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at xxx**

How do I convert xxx> into something that I can read in English?

Comment: Your code is nonfunctional even allowing for `xxx` instead of real resources.   Please edit so that the code is parseable and shows exactly how you are creating the cursor that is giving you trouble.

Answer (score 0):

looks like *collection.find()* returns a list, try iterating through it

```py
for x in collection.find(myquery):
  print(x)
```